# How to handle numerous forms with different fields and data types in the same table?

Tags: database, forms, postgresql, database-design, full-text-search

I need to develop an application where I need to handle more than 30 forms. Those forms have different numbers of fields with different data types. After storage, I need to do advanced search over the forms. A full-text-search may be needed for fields with a specific name shared among forms. Expected data size is ~50k forms with ~500k form fields. PostgreSQL is going to be used.

The solutions that I came up with:

**1. Encoding form fields into a JSON String**

Problems: Performing full-text-search for data with a specific field name can be cumbersome. Also when I need to read or update the data in the form, I need to perform decode and encode.

**2. Creating a table having data fields as much as the number of the inputs in a form**

**Problems:** As the form mapping classes are going to be ready, I can actually map form fields to database fields for each of those forms. For search, I may need to write different rules for each of those forms as the mapping for fields will change radically.

**3. Keeping fields in a different table with a foreign-key to the form table**

**Problems:** Maintaining the form data is still an issue but I don't know about speed. I expect it to run at least as fast as the previous way. Generating the search query from Java/Hibernate will be a bit harder than the previous way.

As I don't have any experience in handling such a case, I need your help and suggestions.

Comment: Why not simply store each form in it's own table

Comment: Because the aggregation of those tables would be so much pain. I need to show general info about those forms when needed. So I need to get data (or search with constraints) from those tables and combine them in a single result.

Comment: This is one of those things where a RDBMS isn't necessarily the best choice.